# Bootstrap navbar right-align button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar

Ran into a strange (maybe I just don't understand this) problem. I'm putting in a navbar at the top (`navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top`), and also trying to put some links that's right-aligned, like so:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

      <li><a href="#">designs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">designers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">buy</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>

  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

      <li><a href="/login">login</a></li>
      <li><a href="/register">sign up</a></li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

[ http://www.bootply.com/dywf7Buv1u ]

This works all well, but if I say, change one of the right-aligned elements to a button wrapped inside a link, then it goes haywire.

Instead of:

```
<li><a href="/register">sign up</a></li>
```

I put in:

```
<li><a href="/register"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small btn-nav">Sign up</button></a></li>
```

[ http://www.bootply.com/DjNB53gJao# ]

You'll see a vertical offset where the button is lower than everything else, which also stretches the entire vertical height of the navbar.

Note that, if you ONLY put the `<button>` inside the `<li>` and do NOT wrap a `<a>` around it, this problem doesn't happen. There's something weird going on when you wrap `<a>` around a `<button>`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your anchor tags can have the `btn` class applied to them. Why are you putting a button inside of them? http://www.bootply.com/byJKxZmRzi

Comment: Because it looks horrible if you just added a button class onto the anchor tags. How do I make it look exactly the same as if it were just a button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a little bit weird but you have to add a `.btn-nav` class on the list item which display the button.

Then, wrap the button in a block element and only after that add a `.navbar-btn` to your button.

See [the demo here](http://www.bootply.com/nus9e5ySnI).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! While it doesn't look amazing on mobile web, it is a solid solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid ">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Recipes</a>
    </div>

    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Recipes</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Shopping</a>

      </ul>

    </div>

    **<div class="nav navbar-right">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
          aria-expanded="false">
          Manage
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Save Data</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Load Data</a></li>
            <li><div class="dropdown-divider"></div></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Export Data</a></li>
      </div>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>**
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi Konstantinos!  While this may answer the question, code-only answers are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow.  Could you consider editing this to also include an English explanation of what you did, and how this answers/solves the problem?  Thanks!